# Add another subtitles to matroska file, on Linux

Tags: linux, subtitles, matroska

I have Matroska file with some subtitles already built in. How can I add another subtitles, with proper language setting and encoding?

Tried:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv -S source.mkv new-subtitles.srt
```

but it looks like it removed all other subtitles. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is because you specified the `-S` parameter when pointing to the source file. `-S` removes all subtitle tracks from input. What you want is actually this:

```
mkvmerge -o myouput.mkv myinput.mkv --language "0:ger" --track-name "0:mytrackname" mynewsubtitles.srt
```

This will append `mynewsubtitles.srt` as the last track with that trackname and language. Also in current versions of mkvmerge the default language is english. So you do not need to set `--language` if that is the case.